# computing missing months in timeseries

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataset in R that contains monthly values.  However, some months are missing.  For example:

"2001-09-01" "2001-10-01" "2001-12-01" "2002-02-01"

Nov 2001 is missing and Jan 2002 is missing.  How do I include those months into the timeseries and add a value of 0 ?

Thanks!

Comment: You will receive more useful answers if you provide the structure of your data object.  Please provide the output of `dput(head(mydata,10))`.

Answer (score 4):

Since this is a monthly series it might make sense to represent it as a series with `"yearmon"` class times.  The first few lines set up the test data and the last two lines do the actual filling:

```
# set up input data as a zoo series
library(zoo)
d <- c("2001-09-01", "2001-10-01", "2001-12-01", "2002-02-01")
z <- zoo(1:4, as.yearmon(d))

# merge with zero width series
g <- seq(start(z), end(z), 1/12)
zz <- merge(z, zoo(, g), fill = 0)
```

If a `"ts"` series is desired then use `as.ts(zz)`  or if a zoo series with times of `"Date"` class is wanted then try: `time(zz) <- as.Date(time(zz))` .

Note that this is also discussed with several examples in FAQ 13 of the zoo FAQ available via the R command `vignette("zoo-faq")` or on the net at:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-faq.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have your data in a `data.frame`, called `dat1`:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c("2001-09-01", "2001-10-01", "2001-12-01", "2002-02-01")),
  val  = 1:4
)
```

You can then create a second `data.frame` that contains a single column with all the dates you need.  Use `seq.Date` to create this sequence:

```
dat2 <- data.frame(
  date = seq(as.Date("2001-09-01"), by="1 month", length.out=7)
)
```

Then it is a simple `merge` operation:

```
merge(dat1, dat2, all=TRUE)
        date val
1 2001-09-01   1
2 2001-10-01   2
3 2001-11-01  NA
4 2001-12-01   3
5 2002-01-01  NA
6 2002-02-01   4
7 2002-03-01  NA
```

The missing values are `NA` but you can then use subsetting to set them to 0, if you desire.